Symmetry/Anti-symmetry property of Riemann curvature tensor
One can check that for a Riemann tensor $R_{abcd}$, using the standard definitions of the symmetry bracket "(...)" and the anti-symmetry bracket "[...]",
\begin{align}
R_{a(bcd)}=0 \quad (\text{using}\ R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc})
\end{align}
\begin{align}
R_{a[bcd]}=0 \quad (\text{first Bianchi identity})
\end{align}
How is it possible that the same set of indices ($b, c, d$ above) are both symmetric and anti-symmetric at the same time?

Well, besides symmetric and antisymmetric tensors, there are tensors of mixed symmetry, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post, so $R_{abcd}$ is not necessarily zero.

That explains it, thanks!
